# Flow Type higher order component (HOC) props type preservation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm bashing my head against the wall on this one. I'm trying to incorporate flowtype into some react projects. For the most part, the typing seems to work great. However, I am using a library (react-jss) which uses a HOC to inject stylesheet classes into your component. The problem is that this module doesn't have flow typings, so it blows away any props validation on my components since all my components are wrapped with this HOC.

I have been able to add some typings based off of some github isuses I saw, so at least I know that I am getting a component back from the react-jss HOC, but this new component has no props associated with it from flow's point of view, so I don't get errors for failing to provide required props or props of the wrong type (eliminating a lot of the benefit of flow). Here's what I copy pasted to get the basic react-jss HOC definition:

```
declare type FunctionComponent<A> = (props: A) => ?React$Element<any>;

declare type ClassComponent<D, A, S> = Class<React$Component<D, A, S>>;

declare type Component<A> = FunctionComponent<A> | ClassComponent<any, A, any>;

declare type Fn1<A, B> = (a: A) => B;

declare type HOC<A, B> = Fn1<Component<A>, Component<B>>;

declare module 'react-jss' {
  declare module.exports: (styleSheet: Object) => HOC<A, B>;
}
```

Keep in mind the rought signature for the react-jss default export (injectStyles) is this:

```
function injectStyles(styleSheet: AnObject)(Component: ReactComponent<Props>): ReactComponent<PropsWithStyleClasses>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these definitions:

```
declare module 'react-jss' {
  // Export these
  declare type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
  declare type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;

  declare type Klasses<CSS> = {
    [classname: $Keys<CSS>]: string,
  };

  declare type JSSProps<CSS> = {
    classes: Klasses<CSS>,
    sheet: {
      attached: boolean,
      classes: Klasses<CSS>,
      deployed: boolean,
      linked: boolean,
      options: Object,
      renderer: mixed,
      rules: mixed,
    },
  };

  declare type Injector = {
    <Props, State, DefaultProps, CSS>(component: ClassComponent<DefaultProps, Props, State>): ClassComponent<DefaultProps, $Diff<Props, JSSProps<CSS>>, void>;
    <Props, CSS>(component: FunctionComponent<Props>): FunctionComponent<$Diff<Props, JSSProps<CSS>>>;
  };

  declare function exports<Props, State, DefaultProps, CSS>(
    CSS: CSS,
  ): Injector
}
```

Note that flow has some issues when you import the injected component. When using a class everything works fine:

```
// Test.js
class Test extends React.Component<void, { text: string }, void> {
    ...
}
export const StyledTest = injectSheet(style)(Test)

// Main.js
...
render() {
    return <StyledTest /> // ERROR here, missing `text` prop
}
```

But for function components, you need to type it explicitly:

```
// Test.js
const Test = (props: { text: string }) => {
    ...
}
export const StyledTest: FunctionComponent<{ text: string }> = injectSheet(style)(Test) // Explicitly type this

// Main.js
...
render() {
     return <StyledTest /> // ERROR here, so it works!
}
```

I'm not sure if these issues were fixed in flow, but this setup works fine for me.